# border of the text-box is overwritten by another class

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

- I am trying to overwrite the material ui css.
- for the textbox I need to give border color as red.
- but the problem is bottom border is overwritten
- when I debugged I found its overwritten by this class MuiInput-underline-904:before
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- providing my code snippet and sandbox below.

https://codesandbox.io/s/nk2ym81qwl

```
  textField: {
    flexBasis: 200,
    border: "1px solid red"
  }

<TextField
          select
          label="With Select"
          className={classNames(classes.margin, classes.textField)}
          value={this.state.weightRange}
          onChange={this.handleChange("weightRange")}
          InputProps={{
            startAdornment: <InputAdornment position="start">Kg</InputAdornment>
          }}
        >
          {ranges.map(option => (
            <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
              {option.label}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </TextField>
```

**problem occurs due to the below code**

```
.MuiInput-underline-904:before {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    content: "\00a0";
    position: absolute;
    transition: border-bottom-color 200ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.42);
    pointer-events: none;
}


<div class="MuiInputBase-root-913 MuiInput-root-900 MuiInput-underline-904 MuiInputBase-formControl-914 MuiInput-formControl-901 MuiInputBase-adornedStart-917">
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
textField {
  flexBasis: 200,
  border: 1px solid red !important;
}
```

Use !important to force your style.

Comment: thanks for your reply...I updated important in sandbox but still its not working...can you update in my sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/nk2ym81qwl

Comment: the underline you are trying to remove is not because of border-bottom, it is a pseudo-element made using ::before pseudo selector to a dynamic MUI class `.MuiInput-underline-xx:before` which is tough to target because you don't have direct access to MUI component's style.

Comment: however, you can choose another select element style from the list, I find second last component matches your need. find the list here [material selects](https://material-ui.com/demos/selects/)

Comment: hey in that code I am getting extra label age, when I select a dropdown value that age is coming outside....can you tell me how to fix it